# Javascript Else If switch using HTML input. Checking a value and displaying a result accordingly. Cost Estimator

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am making a simple cost estimator. I want to make an else if switch that checks the imputed values and displays a certain string dependant on those values. The cost estimation is working but I cant get the Else If switch to function.

Here is my codepen: http://codepen.io/FredHair/pen/FgJAd

I have tried to have a go here:

```
function myContainer(){
    var container;
    var x = Number(document.getElementById("x").value);
    var y = Number(document.getElementById("y").value);
    var z = Number(document.getElementById("z").value);
if (z < 25 && x < 110 && y < 90 ){
container = "1";
}
else if (z < 25 && x < 110 && y < 180 ){
container = "2";
}
else if (z < 25 && x < 220 && y < 90 ){
container = "3";
}
else if (z < 50 && x < 110 && y < 90 ){
container = "4";
}
else if (z < 50 && x < 110 && y < 180 ){
container = "5";
}
else if (z < 50 && x < 220 && y < 90 ){
container = "6";
}
else if (z < 75 && x < 110 && y < 90 ){
container = "7";
}
else if (z < 75 && x < 110 && y < 180 ){
container = "8";
}
else if (z < 75 && x < 220 && y < 90 ){
container = "9";
}
else if (z < 100 && x < 110 && y < 90 ){
container = "10";
}
else if (z < 100 && x < 110 && y < 180 ){
container = "11";
}
else if (z < 100 && x < 220 && y < 90 ){
container = "12";
}
else{
container = "?"
}

 document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = container;
}
```

This is obviously meant to display a value in the HTML h3 id= "container", but currently nothing happens.

Where am I going wrong? is there a much better way to set up this? Using JQuery perhaps? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Sorry for my basic coding.

Comment: you are not calling above function. I have checked your link

Comment: Indeed, the function `myContainer()` is never called.

Comment: You are quite correct I have added "myContainer()" to the Est button. but still nothing displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `myContainer` function is never being called.  If you were to add it to your other function after you display the results, you'd get the results you wanted.  Such as:

```
    ...
    //Display Result//
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " =  £  " + result;
    myContainer();
}
```

That said you could simplify both functions.  For example, the switch statement doesn't really serve much of a purpose, since you can modify your markup to produce the results that you want by changing your values to 50 and 30 such as:

```
<select id="choice" >
  <option value = "1">1</option>
  <option value = "50">2</option>
  <option value = "30">3</option>
</select>
```

Now in your calculator function, you can set the result with a ternary operator.  You read it like an if statement, meaning `(if the value is true) ? (do this) : (else do this)`.

```
function calculator(){
    var x = Number(document.getElementById("x").value);
    var y = Number(document.getElementById("y").value);
    var z = Number(document.getElementById("z").value);
    var choice = Number(document.getElementById("choice").value);
    var result = (choice === 1) ?  z * 3 : x * 3 + choice;  
//Display Result//
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " =  £  " + result;
    myContainer(x,y,z); //pass the values of x, y, z as arguments
}
```

You could simplify your myContainer as well, by passing the values to it for x, y and z directly from the calculator function, then you don't need to go back to the DOM and retrieve those values again.

```
function myContainer(x, y, z){
    var container;

    //all your if-else here ..

    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = container;
}
```